# Serving images directly from s3 or EC2 server in between?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I am building a website where users can upload images and later view them on different devices. I am planning to store images on S3, while my webserver will be running on EC2.

Now, I have a doubt - whether to serve images directly from S3 to client (browser, app etc) or serve them through my webserver in between.

If I serve directly through S3, then webserver will be less loaded but I need to authenticate requests directly going to S3 (as only a user should be able to view his/her images).

Similarly, should I upload images directly to S3 without bringing my webserver in between?

In which case it will be expensive (band-width utilization etc) ?

thanks!

Comment: Serving direct is going to be your best bet. You can provide access to private images via signed urls. As far as upload is concerned, you will probably still need to handle that via your instance to capture any addtional metadata related to the file.

Comment: Thank you. I will read up on signed urls.